# Can we build spinorial eigenstates of Time reversal symmetry?

Tags: spinors, time-reversal-symmetry, parity, cpt-symmetry

In the SM, and general theories with spinors, we can build the Parity left/right eigenspinors. Indeed, there are also [ELKO fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELKO_field), eigenstates of Charge operator (non-standard Wigner classes). Can we build Time reversal operator self-conjugated spinors with non-standard features like we did with ELKO spinors?